# What step am I missing or do I have in the wrong order that is causing this PDF writing to fail?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, filestream

I've got this code that produces a PDF file, but it won't open, Edge telling me when I try, "*Couldn't open PDF. Something's keeping this PDF from opening.*"

Here is the code that is somehow goofed up/haywire (unpertinent and redundant code elided):

```
public static void GenerateAndEmailScheduleToChairmen(int year, int month)
{
    . . .
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 
25))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();

                    // Title
                    PdfPTable titleTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                    Paragraph title = new Paragraph(
                        $"CHAIRMEN'S SCHEDULE FOR 
{AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetMonthForInt(month)}, {year}");
                    title.Font.SetFamily("Verdana");
                    title.Font.Size = 16;

                    var titleCell = new PdfPCell();
                    titleCell.AddElement(title);
                    titleTable.AddCell(titleCell);
                    doc.Add(titleTable);

                    // Column Headings
                    PdfPTable tblHeadings = new PdfPTable(6)
                    {
                        WidthPercentage = 80,
                        SpacingBefore = 10f
                    };
                    float[] headingRowWidths = new float[] {180f, 180f, 
180f, 180f, 100f, 180f};
                    tblHeadings.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                    tblHeadings.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                    Phrase phraseWeekBeginningHeading = new Phrase("Week 
Beginning", courier11BoldYellow);
                    PdfPCell cellWeekBeginningHeading = 
GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseWeekBeginningHeading,
                        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BaseColor.BLUE);
                    tblHeadings.AddCell(cellWeekBeginningHeading);

                    . . .

                    // Main Contents

                    DateTime prevD8 = 
humanFriendlyAssignmentVals[0].WeekOfAssignment.Date;
                    foreach (AssignmentStudentMashup asmRec in 
humanFriendlyAssignmentVals)
                    {
                        // add a paragraph break when the week changes
                        PdfPTable tblRow;
                        if (asmRec.WeekOfAssignment.Date != prevD8)
                        {
                            tblRow = new PdfPTable(6)
                            {
                                WidthPercentage = 80,
                                SpacingBefore = 10f
                            };
                            headingRowWidths = new[] {180f, 180f, 180f, 
180f, 100f, 180f};
                            tblRow.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                            tblRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                            // Add blank row
                            var phraseblankRow = new Phrase();
                            var cellBlankRow = new PdfPCell(phraseblankRow) 
{BorderWidth = 0};
                            tblRow.AddCell(cellBlankRow);
                        }
                        prevD8 = asmRec.WeekOfAssignment;
                        tblRow = new PdfPTable(6)
                        {
                            WidthPercentage = 80,
                            SpacingBefore = 10f
                        };
                        headingRowWidths = new[] {180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 
100f, 180f};
                        tblRow.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                        tblRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                        var phraseWeekBeginning = new 
Phrase(asmRec.WeekOfAssignment.ToLongDateString(),
                            courier11BoldYellow);
                        var cellWeekBeginning = 
GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseWeekBeginning,
                            Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BaseColor.BLUE);
                        tblRow.AddCell(cellWeekBeginning);

                        . . .
                        doc.Add(tblHeadings);
                    } // writer
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    String PDFFileName = 
$"ChairmensCounselInfo_{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}.pdf";
                    PDFFileName = PDFFileName.Replace(":", "_");
                    var chairmansPDFFile = $"C:\\AYttFMApp\\{PDFFileName}";
                    File.WriteAllBytes(chairmansPDFFile, bytes);
                    MessageBox.Show($"{PDFFileName} written");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(${ex.Message});
    }
}
```

I see the "file written" messagebox.show, but then a "*cannot access a closed stream*"

### UPDATE

I am creating the MemoryStream now without a using close, and closing the doc prior to writing, but I still get a message that the PDF file (although it does have some content (2KB)) cannot be opened.

I think the "writer" is at least part of the problem, as without it, the PDF is 0KB, but with it, "writer" is grayed out, as if it is not being used. Here is my code now (with only those differences mentioned above):

```
    try
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25))
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                doc.Open();

                // Title
                PdfPTable titleTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                Paragraph title = new Paragraph(
                    $"CHAIRMEN'S SCHEDULE FOR 
{AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetMonthForInt(month)}, {year}");
                title.Font.SetFamily("Verdana");
                title.Font.Size = 16;

                var titleCell = new PdfPCell();
                titleCell.AddElement(title);
                titleTable.AddCell(titleCell);
                doc.Add(titleTable);

                // Column Headings
                PdfPTable tblHeadings = new PdfPTable(6)
                {
                    WidthPercentage = 80,
                    SpacingBefore = 10f
                };
                float[] headingRowWidths = new float[] { 180f, 180f, 180f, 
180f, 100f, 180f };
                tblHeadings.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                tblHeadings.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                Phrase phraseWeekBeginningHeading = new Phrase("Week 
Beginning", courier11BoldYellow);
                PdfPCell cellWeekBeginningHeading = 
GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseWeekBeginningHeading,
                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BaseColor.BLUE);
                tblHeadings.AddCell(cellWeekBeginningHeading);

                . . .

                // Main Contents

                DateTime prevD8 = 
humanFriendlyAssignmentVals[0].WeekOfAssignment.Date;
                foreach (AssignmentStudentMashup asmRec in 
humanFriendlyAssignmentVals)
                {
                    // add a paragraph break when the week changes
                    PdfPTable tblRow;
                    if (asmRec.WeekOfAssignment.Date != prevD8)
                    {
                        tblRow = new PdfPTable(6)
                        {
                            WidthPercentage = 80,
                            SpacingBefore = 10f
                        };
                        headingRowWidths = new[] { 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 
100f, 180f };
                        tblRow.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                        tblRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                        // Add blank row
                        var phraseblankRow = new Phrase();
                        var cellBlankRow = new PdfPCell(phraseblankRow) 
{ BorderWidth = 0 };
                        tblRow.AddCell(cellBlankRow);
                    }
                    prevD8 = asmRec.WeekOfAssignment;
                    tblRow = new PdfPTable(6)
                    {
                        WidthPercentage = 80,
                        SpacingBefore = 10f
                    };
                    headingRowWidths = new[] { 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 100f, 
180f };
                    tblRow.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
                    tblRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                    var phraseWeekBeginning = new 
Phrase(asmRec.WeekOfAssignment.ToLongDateString(),
                        courier11BoldYellow);
                    var cellWeekBeginning = 
GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseWeekBeginning,
                        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BaseColor.BLUE);
                    tblRow.AddCell(cellWeekBeginning);

                    . . .
                    var phraseCounselPoint = new 
Phrase(asmRec.CounselPointStr, courier11BoldYellow);
                    var cellCounselPoint 
GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseCounselPoint, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                        BaseColor.BLUE);
                    tblRow.AddCell(cellCounselPoint);
                    doc.Add(tblHeadings);
                } // writer
                var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                String PDFFileName = 
$"ChairmensInfo_{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}.pdf";
                PDFFileName = PDFFileName.Replace(":", "_");
                var chairmansPDFFile = $"C:\\AYttFMApp\\{PDFFileName}";
                doc.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes(chairmansPDFFile, bytes);
                MessageBox.Show($"{PDFFileName} written");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DocumentException dex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"DocumentException: {dex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
    catch (IOException ioex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"IOException: {ioex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"General Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
```

I'm not seeing any exception messages.

### UPDATE 2

Okay, this is what it took to work:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25))
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
    doc.Open();
    . . . // contents added to the file, same as before
    doc.Add(tblHeadings);
} // using doc
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
String PDFFileName = $"ChairmensCounselInfo_{DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}.pdf";
PDFFileName = PDFFileName.Replace(":", "_");
var chairmansPDFFile = $"C:\\AYttFMApp\\{PDFFileName}";
File.WriteAllBytes(chairmansPDFFile, bytes);
MessageBox.Show($"{PDFFileName} written");
```

Comment: What you say in your update and the code that follows is in contradiction. You say you are *closing the doc prior to writing* but that's not true: you are writing `ms` to `bytes` prior to closing the doc. What you are doing goes against elementary logic. Also: you don't need to close the `doc` when you're using `using`.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that you can now see how to interpret my initial answer.

Comment: B. Clay Shannon, you have non-working code and try to make it work seemingly without knowing what to do. How about instead starting from working code (e.g. the basic [HelloWorld.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/blob/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter01/HelloWorld.cs)) and changing it step by step, testing after each change to see what change introduces the error. We of course can give you hints concerning your use of iTextSharp classes (@Bruno already does a great job here) but we don't know whether all the other stuff you use works as expected.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for clarifying. I have already answered many questions posted by B. Clay Shannon in the past year; by now B. Clay Shannon should already have some experience with iTextSharp. Unfortunately, it's as if this book is the only resource B. Clay Shannon wants to use: https://twitter.com/thepracticaldev/status/705825638851149824 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `MemoryStream` to create an `byte` array *before* the `Document` is closed. This results in an incomplete PDF.

At the end of the `using` that creates the `Document`, the PDF is completed (e.g. the essential cross-reference table is written), but by then, you've already used the incomplete stream to write the PDF file.

How to solve this?

Don't use `using` to create the `MemoryStream`. Wait until the `Document` is closed before writing the bytes of the `MemoryStream` to a PDF file.

**UPDATE:**

You didn't follow my advice correctly in your update. You have something like:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25))
{
    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
    {
        doc.Open();
        // adding content
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        doc.Close();
        // write bytes to a file.
    }
}
```

As I explained earlier, this is wrong. You are writing the content of an incomplete PDF to an array of bytes named `bytes`. That PDF is corrupt because it doesn't have a cross-reference table. The cross-reference table is only created when you `Close()` the document, either explicitly or implicitly. You now `Close()` the document explicitly after creating the `bytes` array. That's too late.

You need something like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25))
{
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms));
    doc.Open();
    // adding content
}
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
// write bytes to a file
```

If you don't need `writer`, you can even do this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25))
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms));
    doc.Open();
    // adding content
}
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
// write bytes to a file
```

Just make sure that you create the complete PDF:

1. don't close the `writer` *before* the `Document` has had a chance to close.
2. don't use `ms` *before* the `Document` has had a chance to close.